# UIView. How do I redisplay a "data driven" UIView?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, drawrect

I am doing a scientific visualization app for iPhone. Periodically a UIView subclass will receive some data from the network that it must render via its overridden drawRect: method.

My challenge is that there is no way to indicate to Cocoa-Touch that this data has arrived - or changed - other then [myView setNeedsDisplay] which is ignored except for changes to the bounds of the UIView. I have tried hiding and unhiding. Nuthin'.

Maddeningly, since all I did was alter some internal state of the UIView [myView setNeedsDisplay]. This change is completely invisible to Cocoa-Touch. This change is not one of the criteria that warrents a redraw - according to Cocoa-Touch - thus my UIView sits there, unchanged.

This is very, very, very frustrating. I have hit a wall here.

Could someone please suggest a technique, a trick, a hack, that will prompt my UIView to re-render.

Cheers,
Doug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[myView setNeedsDisplay]` should cause `drawRect:` to be sent to `myView` the next time you're back in the run loop and `myView` is visible. If changing the bounds is causing the view to redraw (`myView.contentMode` is `UIViewContentModeRedraw`), then `setNeedsDisplay` must be working, since that's how the redraw is signalled by the bounds change. See the [UIView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay) for details.

Is your `drawRect:` being invoked the first time the view is shown? If not, it may be misspelled, overridden in a subclass, or even on the wrong object.

Is the view visible and on screen? It won't be drawn if it is off screen.

Is control returning to the event loop? `drawRect:` won't be invoked if your application is busy.

Comment: Will,
Ok this is weird. I had removed a call to [myView setNeedsDisplay] because it wasn't previously doing anything. I just put it back and drawRect is firing away. Sigh. Thanks for the assist.